# Integrating PhoneGap with Game Center

Tags: cordova, game-center

Is there any way to make a game with HTML, CSS and JavaScript(+ jQuery) and use PhoneGap to make it a native iOS app and then integrating it with Game Center?

What I have in mind is to make a game similar to [travian](http://www.travian.com/). I mean a kind of game which you only play with text and number, and no animation involved. I know if I use Unity or Game Maker, then I can add Game Center to my game, but the type of game I wanna make is not easy with those game engines.

I need Game Center for its high number of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or there is this new plugin compatible with phonegap 3.x:
https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-game-center

And with a very nice documentation:

http://ilee.co.uk/using-game-center-with-phonegap/

Comment: I have just recently used this plugin and it worked great. About to commit a few extra features to it once I get the time.

Comment: Great! I plan to use it too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin on Github which has game center access for PhoneGap.

https://github.com/phyx3r/Game-Center-Phonegap-Plugin